# C++ MySQL insert error?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, insert

I'm creating a card-related program in C++, which uses a database. After receiving student names and numbers as input, it stops when I trun the INSERT.

[image]

▲ DB Create Detail (hakbun, name)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mysql.h>
#include<conio.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"libmysql.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

#define DB_HOST "localhost"  
#define DB_USER "root"   
#define DB_PASS "1234" 
#define DB_NAME "point_db" 

void DBconnect() {

 MYSQL *connection = NULL, conn;
 MYSQL_RES *sql_result;
 MYSQL_ROW sql_row;

 mysql_init(&conn);
 connection = mysql_real_connect(&conn, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, 3306, (char *)NULL, 0);
 if (connection == NULL){
  printf("con error");
 }

 mysql_query(connection, "set session character_set_connection=euckr;");
 mysql_query(connection, "set session character_set_results=euckr;");
 mysql_query(connection, "set session character_set_client=euckr;");
}

int main()
{
 MYSQL *connection = NULL, conn;
 MYSQL_RES *sql_result;
 MYSQL_ROW sql_row;

 DBconnect();

 int query_stat;
 char query[1024];
 char num;

 while (1) {

  cout << "           +--------------------+" << endl;
  cout << "           | ① create card   |" << endl;
  cout << "           +--------------------+" << endl;
  cout << "              input number > ";
  cin >> num;

  switch (num) {

  case '1':

   int i, hakbun, student;
   char name;

   cout << "student id : ";
   cin >> hakbun;
   cout << "mame : ";
   cin >> name;

   // insert
   sprintf_s(query, "insert into point(hakbun, name) values('%d','%s')", hakbun, name);

   query_stat = mysql_query(connection, query);
   if (query_stat != 0){
    printf("error : %s", mysql_error(&conn));
    return 1;
   }

  default:
   cout << "end program" << endl;
   exit(0);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `name` as `char` and you use `%s` to `sprint` it. Try to print `query` on the screen to see what query you send to MySql. Either you declare `name` as a string:

```
char name[50];
```

or use `%c` instead of `%s`

Comment: So how do I change it?
You must enter a different character, not a single character.

Comment: @MinjuPark It should be a `char` array or `std::string`.

Comment: @MinjuPark I modified the answer

Comment: @MinjuPark `char` can only hold 1 character, not a whole name. This is beginning C++, nothing to do with the database.

Comment: The Chinese are multiple outputs. The letters are printed as broken.

Comment: by cout << query << endl;

Comment: sprintf_s(query, "insert into point(hakbun, name) values('%d','%c')", hakbun, name);  I looked to try to fix submitted corrected answers were unsuccessful.
In this context it seems there is a problem with the query.
The Chinese are multiple outputs.

Comment: `char` is not enough. The field `name` is `varchar(30)` in your DB. Declare `name` as a string (see my answer) and use `%s`. If you still have encoding problems, use `wchar_t` instead of `char` @MinjuPark